# Deriving Data from Multiple Tables & Joining in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Users will be recording data using the following two tables:

**USERS:**

```
UserID UserName UserType
    1    Tom     5
    2    Mike    6
    3    Joe     6
```

**RECORDINGS :**

```
 UserID Recording
    1    10
    1    15
```

I want to use a single query to find the Name, and the count of recordings made by each user whose UserType is above the average of UserType.  In the event a user has never made a recording, it needs to be 0 (not null or missing).

My approach is to first select the users who are above average, second to select the count of recordings made by each user, and third to join the two where UserID matches.  Is there a more straight forward approach?

Comment: 1) pick users whose number of recordings > the average number of recordings in the whole table or 2) pick users whose number of recordings >  the average number of recordings in his/her group. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT usr.UserID
      ,COUNT(rec.Recording) Count
  FROM USers usr
      ,Recordings rec
      ,(SELECT AVG(UserType) average
          FROM USers usr1) avg1
 WHERE usr.Userid = rec.userid(+)
   AND avg1.average < usr.UserType
 GROUP BY usr.UserID
```

Please check if this works.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a03d2/5/0